# Wrap a Golang HTTP middleware to a GRPC interceptor

Tags: go, grpc

I've a Golang service that has a lot of http middleware (for token introspection, monitoring, logging...), and I'm currently integrating some GRPC methods to the same service.

To not implement the same middleware for GRPC, I want to know if there are some existing wrappers that can convert an HTTP to a GRPC interceptor?

For example, if I do this manually, if I have an HTTP middleware like this one:

```golang
func AnHTTPMiddleware() func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "a-context-metadata", uuid.NewString()))
            next.ServeHTTP(rw, r)
        })
    }
}
```

Then I've also to implement this:

```golang
func AGRPCMiddleware(ctx context.Context, req any, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (any, error) {
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "a-context-metadata", uuid.NewString())
    return handler(ctx, req)
}
```

To have the same behavior in GRPC.
What I wanted to do is using a generic interceptor that can convert the HTTP middleware to the GRPC interceptor. About the `http.ResponseWriter` it's easy to extend it and override methods the get/set values on GRPC context and metadata. But about `http.Request`, the structure contains some publicly accessible fields, so we need to map it, it introduces some additional mapping.

Is their some generic method to do this? Can we use some method from [grpc gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) (that already convert grpc to http handlers) to do achieve this?